# Computing monodromy eigenvalues of a generic arrangement

Tags: algebraic-topology

First the set-up:

Let $f = \Pi_{i=1}^{d} f_{i} \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ be a generic, homogoeneous hyperplane arrangement of degree d. Let M be the complement of $f^{-1}(0)$, $F = f^{-1}(0)$, and $p: \mathbb{C}^{2} \to \mathbb{C}P^{1}$ the standard projectivizing map. Then identifying $p(M)$ with the orbit space of M under the action of $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ we see that $p(M)$ is homeomorphic to $\frac{M}{\mathbb{C}^{*}}$ which is homeomorphic to $\frac{F}{<\zeta>}$ where $<\zeta>$ is the action by the dth root of unity.

Consider the following fibration: $ \{\zeta x_{0}, ..., \zeta^{d} x_{0}\} \to F \to \frac{F}{<\zeta>}$. Applying the Leray-Serre spectral sequence to this fibration and noting that because $H_{i}(\{\zeta x_{0}, ..., \zeta^{d} x_{0}\})$ is zero for $i \geq 1$ we deduce $H_{n}(F, \mathbb{C}) = H_{n}(\frac{F}{<\zeta>}, H_{0}(\zeta x_{0}, ..., \zeta^{d} x_{0}\}, \mathbb{C}))$

Now the wedge sum of d-1 circles is a deformation retract of $\frac{F}{<\zeta>}$. (To see this note $\frac{F}{<\zeta>}$ is just $\mathbb{C}P$ minus d points.) Let $d: \frac{F}{<\zeta>} \to \vee_{1}^{d-1} S^{1}$ be said deformation retraction.

Finally let $h: M \to M$ be the geometric monodromy (so multiplication by the dth root of unity) and $h^{*}$ the algebraic monodromy.

I have two questions.

Question 1:

Is it possible to compute the action of $h^{*}$ on $H_{n}(\frac{F}{<\zeta>}, H_{0}(\zeta x_{0}, ..., \zeta^{d} x_{0}\}, \mathbb{C}))$ by using this deformation retraction? I suppose what I am asking is if the diagram commutes, i.e. if $h^{*} \circ d^{*} = d^{*} \circ h^{*}$.

Question 2: Assuming Question 1 returns true my instinct would be to take a good cover of my wedge of circles and get my hands dirty. So, my question here is basically what is wrong with the following argument:

Let $U_{i}^{k}$, $1 \leq i \leq 3$ be the standard good cover of the circle (so three arcs basically). I deduce $H_{1}(\vee_{1}^{d-1} S^{1}, G)$ is just $\Pi_{1}^{d-1} (G(U_{1}^{i}), G(U_{1}^{i}), -G(U_{1}^{i}))$. Thus $H_{1}(\frac{F}{<\zeta>}, H_{0}(\zeta x_{0}, ..., \zeta^{d} x_{0}\}, \mathbb{C}))$ is $\Pi_{1}^{d-1} (d^{*-1}(G(U_{1}^{i})), d^{*-1}(G(U_{1}^{i})), d^{*-1}(-G(U_{1}^{i})))$. Now I know how $h^{*}$ works on $H_{1}(\frac{F}{<\zeta>}, H_{0}(\zeta x_{0}, ..., \zeta^{d} x_{0}\}, \mathbb{C}))$: if I fix an open set V and a section on V (a_{1}, ..., a_{d}), $h^{*}$ just sends that section to (a_{2}, ..., a_{1}). Thus the matrix $h^{*}$ induces on the first homology group is the $3(d-1)d \times 3(d-1)d$ matrix with $  \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 &... & 1 \\
1 & 0 &... & 0 \\
... & ... & ... & ...\\
0 & ... & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right)$ on the diagonals. Since this matrix sends vectors of the form $[(a_{1}, ..., a_{d}),(a_{1}, ..., a_{d}), -(a_{1}, ..., a_{d}), (b_{1}, ..., b_{d}), ...]$ to vectors of the same form it is more accurate to think of $h^{*}$ as the $d(d-1) \times d(d-1)$ matrix with $  \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 &... & 1 \\
1 & 0 &... & 0 \\
... & ... & ... & ...\\
0 & ... & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right)$ on the diagonals. (This is consistent as $H_{1}$ should be $\mathbb{C}^{d(d-1)}$). Now this implies the eigenvalues of $h^{*}$ are the dth roots of unity and every corresponding eigenspace has dimension d-1. (This is because the repeated matrix on the diagonal has eigenvalues the dth roots of unity and each corresponding eigenspace has dimension 1.)

However, this contradicts a paper I have been looking at where 1 should have corresponding eigenspace of dimension d-1 and the rest should have eigenspaces of dimension d-2.

Any help in seeing what I have done wrong in the argument would be greatly appricated. I am only just starting to get used to all of this machinery so apologies for any awkwardness or hilariously bad reasoning.